# Some functions don't work after .append

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, autocomplete, append

i have a working form that uses [autocomplete](http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/) and [mask](http://digitalbush.com/projects/masked-input-plugin/). I decided to make my form more user-friendly and started using [tabs](http://jqueryui.com/tabs/) and [ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) to load the content. To view the desired form i'm using [.append()](http://api.jquery.com/append/) to create a new tab and display the content in it, instead of a new browser window. After append, the fields inside the newly-created tab, who are supposed to be autocompleted, are not, while as if i copy the exact same field and paste infront (not in the .append tab), it **has** the autocomplete. Same goes with the mask.

My question is how exactly does [.append()](http://api.jquery.com/append/) work? Do i have to load some js and jquery functions **after** appending in order for them to take effect?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure since you didn't show your code, however it's probably that you call `autocomplete()` function on your element inside `onReady` when your element is not already present, because surely you are adding the content of your `tabs` dynamically using `append()` after `onReady`.

The thing is that you must check that you call `autocomplete()` when your element is really present in your `tab`.

I give you an example where I `append` and element on the `tab` and then when the element is present I call `autocomplete()`, and works correctly. Check it out:

```js
$(function() {
    $( "#tabs" ).tabs();
  
    $('#appendButton').click(function(){
      
      // create auto
 var $auto = $('<div class="ui-widget"><label for="tags">Tags: <\/label><input id="tags"><\/div>');
 
    // append auto
    $('#tabs-1').append($auto);
      console.log('autocomplete');
 // once is appened start autocomplete
    var availableTags = [
      "ActionScript",
      "AppleScript",
      "Asp",
      "BASIC",
      "C",
      "C++",
      "Clojure",
      "COBOL",
      "ColdFusion",
      "Erlang",
      "Fortran",
      "Groovy",
      "Haskell",
      "Java",
      "JavaScript",
      "Lisp",
      "Perl",
      "PHP",
      "Python",
      "Ruby",
      "Scala",
      "Scheme"
    ];
    $('#tags').autocomplete({
      source: availableTags
    });
      
   });
  
});
```

```html
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.2/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
 
<div id="tabs">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#tabs-1">Nunc tincidunt</a></li>
  </ul>
  <div id="tabs-1">
    <p> <input id="appendButton" type="button" onclick"appendAuto();" value="appendAuto" /></p>
  </div>
</div>
 
</body>
</html>
```

Hope this helps,

Comment: Exactly what i was thinking.  Thank you